# Automated Re-fetching on removed item

Tags: redux, redux-toolkit, rtk-query

I've got a problem with preventing query from refetching after deleting resource (and invalidating tag).

I have similar situation like the one described [here](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/usage/pagination#automated-re-fetching-of-paginated-queries), but I've got additional `getPost` query for fetching post details. I'm on the post details page, and there is a remove button that will redirect visitor to the list of posts after 200 from backend.

Using code from RTK-Q example I'm getting following result:

```
[DELETE] 200 /deletePost
[GET] 404 /getPost
```

After receiving 200 from delete action I'm invalidating `{ type: 'Posts' as const, id }` tag which causes refetch, because I still have an active connection to the query on the post details page and get 404 from backend because post do not exists anymore.

Is there any chance to prevent `getPost` query from refetching after invalidating tag?

Comment: I have the same issue, with the same tagging and I've not worked out a solution that doesn't require changing the UX. 

To work around it, I set a `skip` property in state to `true` right before I call the delete trigger. This gets used to skip the read useQuery hook (https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/usage/conditional-fetching). If delete fails it sets skip back to false, otherwise it navigates away.

Answer (score 0):

Either don't provide the tag or don't invalidate the tag. You can also choose to introduce more tags like "post_del" and "post_edit" and provide both, but only invalidate one to describe exactly when you want to invalidate something.

Comment: unfortunately Your solutions doesn't work. I need tags to trigger refetching list after actions like add/edit/delete. Providing tags only for the lists as well as not using tags at all and not invalidating tags ends up with same behaviour as described in original post. I've also checked the solution with additional tags, but if getPost has both tags and one of them get invalidated, then there will also be a refetch. Or maybe I'm missing something? I thing what I need is to unsubscribe the resource together with invalidate tag to prevent refetching.

Answer (score 0):

`getPost()` after deletion happens if you have an active subscription to this query somewhere else or if you component is still mounted.

In my case it happened when I called `await delete(id).unwrap()` and then `navigation.pop()`. It means component still exists when object is already deleted on the server, which forces RTKQ to query server again. It's invisible to human and Redux Debugger helped me to understand the sequence of actions.

The solution is to switch two lines and do navigation first and delete() next.

Comment: From the UX perspective it is not always correct way, error handling and loadinc indication should be shown on the screen where you are triggering the delete.